# network (with defined IPs) in another network (with DHCP) - connection issues

Tags: ip, network-share, internal-dns

We develop a client-server application where the server needs to be available with a known IP-address. Therefore, we configure router and PC with defined IP-addresses. This works fine, as long as everything is at the customers place.

If the hardware is connected to our office network, everything breaks after a time, because we have a DHCP that automatically assigns IP-addresses.

Is there a way to have a network inside our DHCP network where some devices have defined IP-addresses? We would like to prepare PC and router with fixed addresses and still be able to connect them to our network. What is an official term for this I could search for?

*Update*

Our network A (with defined IPs in range 192.168.0.XXX) contains two PCs, a switch and and access point for WiFi. In network B (there is DHCP setting IPs in the range 192.168.1.XXX). We could not find an explicit "ignore" function, but since the DHCP is applied 192.168.1.20 to 192.168.1.200, I think the IPs of 192.168.0.XXX should be ignored. Connecting the switch of network A to our network B allows us to go online in network A with a couple of connection issues.

Comment: I assume you mean DHCP for dynamic addresses...Just about every DHCP server can be configured to skip specific addresses, making your static IPs viable. But honestly: can't you just configure the IPs in your application so clients can use any IP they want? Or "even" DNS?

Comment: You were right with DHCP thanks. We had issues with an extra WiFi generated via an access point. We didn't really understand what went wrong.

Comment: If a rogue DHCP server or whatever was your problem, please answer and accept your own question.

Comment: I doubt that there is any rogue server attacking us, but it could definitely be the case that our DHCP is interfering with network A. I tried to configure it that the IPs of network A would be ignored as @Lenniey suggested, but I ended up with weird connection issues. Could these by caused by wrong configuration?

Answer (score 0):

All devices of network A (with defined IPs) have to be in the same sub network, but in a range that is skipped by the DHCP of network B. Make sure to disable DHCP in the access point.

- Example network A:

  - Access Point: 192.168.1.1
  - PC 1: 192.168.1.2
  - PC 2: 192.168.1.3
- DHCP range in network B: from 192.168.1.50 to 192.168.1.200
- Standard gateway and DNS IP had to be set for network A for instance like this:

  - 192.168.1.254 (coming from network B)

*Configuration that did not work (or had connection issues)*:

- Example network A:

  - Access Point: 192.168.0.1
  - PC 1: 192.168.0.2
  - PC 2: 192.168.0.3
    I assume, because it was a different sub network.